# Can't get TCP response in android

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, timeout

The code is supposed to connect as a client to a TCP server, send a command and receive a response.

The code connects and sends the command but time-out-s at "socket.getInputStream()", even though the connected server receives the command and is supposed to respond (was checked using a TCP client program on the PC).

Here Is the Code for the task:

```
public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String dstAddress;
    int dstPort;
    String command;
    String response = "";

    MyClientTask(String addr, int port, String cmd){
        dstAddress = addr;
        dstPort = port;
        command = cmd;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        Socket socket = null;
        InputStream inputStream;

        try {
            socket = new Socket();
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(dstAddress, dstPort),2000);
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);
            out.println(command);

            inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            socket.setSoTimeout(20000);
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
            }

        }catch (UnknownHostException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "Throwable: " + e.toString();
        }finally{
            if(socket != null){
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        textResponse.setText(response);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}//MyClientTask
```

Comment: Correction: it actually time-outs at "inputStream.read(buffer)"

Answer (score 0):

You're reading the response until end of stream. End of stream won't occur until the peer closes the connection. You got a read timeout: *ergo,* probably, he didn't close the connection. Or else your timeout is too short. Two seconds isn't much.

You need a proper way of reading the response, or of dealing with the parts as they arrive.

Comment: I see. Doesn't the read request stop when it has read "buffer.length" bytes? (Reducing the buffer size didn't help)

Comment: Of course it does, but you have it *inside a loop* that only terminates at end of stream. I didn't say anything about the buffer size, or reducing it.

Comment: The loop doesn't seem to be the problem, it timeouts on: "inputStream.read(buffer)". That is, replacing the entire loop with just "bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer,0,1);" still timeouts.

Comment: Replacing the entire loop with what? If you mean you still get a timeout on a single read, or on the first read in the loop, either the server hasn't responded at all or your timeout is too short. Are you sure you're sending a valid command? And if the command is really a line, surely the response is a line as well? In which case you can use `BufferedReader.readLine()` instead of all that code.

Comment: I get a timeout on a single read. The same command returns an instant response to a TCP client I run on my PC. Besides, I have an external indication form the server, that a valid command was received.

Comment: Have you tried a longer timeout yet? And are the requests really lines?

Comment: Apparently, the difference was that the TCP client software adds an "end line" to the end of the command. Now it responds, I'll try using BufferedReader.readLine(). Thanks!

Comment: You're calling `println()`, which does the same thing, but what it adds depends on the local system, which may not agree with what the remote system expects. Try `print()` with various manual newlines: `\n`, `\r\n`, etc, and a `flush()` afterwards.

Comment: Thanks a lot, appending "\r\n" and using print() and flush() did the trick. However, as-per-your recommendation I switched to  BufferedReader.readLine() and I have the following problem: every other time I run the task, readLine returns a zero-length line, instead of the expected response. I've tried adding a second readLine in this case, but it time-out-s. Moreover, using Wireshark I've noticed that each transmission gets 2 responds, one with zero-length line and one as expected. Is it possible that occasionally readLine misses a line?